# Creat new admin url for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I have a custom post type called newsletter. Once the newsletter is created I want to create a link to download the newsletter from the admin section (the newsletter post type is not accessible from the front end of the wordpress site). When the download link is clicked it will run a function in my plugin. The question is how do I register a url with wordpress that will do such a thing? I'm sure this is something pretty simple and I'm just missing it.

Comment: Are you specifically wanting permalinks and pretty URLs? If so you could have a huge uphill battle depending on the form you want to take. Or do you mean how would you implement the button and how to place it in the backend? If you could clarify further with examples diagrams etc it would help greatly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want (probably) [`add_submenu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page). The first parameter-- the one listed as `$parent_slug` in the Codex is going to be `edit.php?post_type=your-post-type-name`, like this (mostly cribbed from the Codex page):

```
function add_submenu_wpse_81844() {
  add_submenu_page( 
      'edit.php?post_type=your-post-type-name'
    , 'My Custom Submenu Page' 
    , 'My Custom Submenu Page'
    , 'manage_options'
    , 'my-custom-submenu-page'
    , 'my_custom_submenu_page_callback'
  );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_submenu_wpse_81844');
```

Check the Codex for what the other parameters mean.

Comment: thanks that's what I needed. Do you know if there is a way to create a submenu without it showing in the sidebar? Basically this link will only be used to download the newsletter which is accessed through a button when the posts are listed.

Comment: I believe you can pass `null` as the first parameter. See the Codex page.

Comment: yes you can do null. In my case I set it to options.php which achieves the same results. thanks.

Comment: one other small issue. Is there a way to prevent the admin theme from being output? Since I'm streaming a zip file to the client, I don't want the admin wrapper. I didn't see anything on the codex page about it.

Comment: For anyone interested the above question about the admin wrapper ended up getting answered here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82041/prevent-admin-gui-output-from-page-added-using-add-submenu-page